# to_datetime formats the data but it doesn't convert the data type of the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, data-manipulation

```
test = pd.DataFrame(
    {
            'localtime': ['25/11/2020 12:26:00', '25/11/2020 18:31:00', '6/12/2020 16:15'],
    }
    )
```

I've converted a column in a dataframe using
`test['localtime']=pd.to_datetime(test['localtime'],errors='coerce',dayfirst=True).dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")`

This formats the data as specified but it doesn't convert the datatype of the column, it remains as `object`. So to achieve the column type as `datetime64[ns]`, I have to add another line

`test['localtime'] = pd.to_datetime(test['localtime'])`

Can I know why this occurs? Is there a way I can achieve the datatype of column as `datetime64[ns]`, without adding the second line?

[image]

Comment: In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you provide a minimal reproducible problem set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the example. What you have provided falls short of this goal. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Comment: @itprorh66 Understood and I have updated the question, thank you

Comment: Can you clarify your question, are you saying that the end result of a localtime column contents doesn't result in a datetime(ns) object if you don't perform the second transformation and you want to understand why this happens?

Comment: why dont you just do test["localtime"] = pd.to_datetime(test["localtime"]) as it does what you want: test.dtypes ->  datetime64[ns]

Comment: The reason the first statement doesn't result in a datetime(ns) object is because you have coerced the result to only Hours and miniutes with the use of  ```.dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") ``` .  The second statement restores the contents of the localtime column to a full datetime(ns) field

Comment: `.dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")` returns **string type** as the name suggests (string from time).

Comment: What's the goal of the first line? Why not stop at `test['localtime']=pd.to_datetime(test['localtime'],errors='coerce',dayfirst=True)`? Does that not do what you want?

Comment: @Joooeey I need to specify the format of the datetime since for certain columns (which was not mentioned in the above sample dataframe) it's in different format

Comment: Then edit your example because I don't understand what you mean.